# Use text representations of LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

In my project, i use a lot of LINQ expressions and i would allow users to type their own queries by typing a linq query in a text input

So, is it possible to create a LINQ expression from a text containing this one ?
And, moreover, is it possible to get the text equivalent of a linq query ? (like from FOO in bar select foo)

Thank's by advance

Comment: Yes and yes, but I don't have time to research now. You can execute lines of code in .Net, but they have to be wrapped in a class, compiled and called as a method. You can do this in separate AppDomains if you need to be able to "unload" the code (clean up memory). You can also lay out LINQ queries by debug printing them. I saw this in one of the initial LINQ seminars I was attending. Sorry I can't dig into details, got to run now.

Comment: For the first what you want is an eval equilant for C#. Google it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try **NLinq**: http://nlinq.codeplex.com

Comment: This seems to be perfect ! Thank's

Answer (score 2):

If you were to take on this task, you would essentially be doing the job of the compiler (taking text representation of an expression and creating an expression tree out of it.  This is a lot of work and probably not worth your time.  The first thought that comes to mind is to have other's type in the linq query and then you compile it on the fly.  The obvious downside to this is that once an assembly is loaded in memory, you can't unload it (unless you start using AppDomains), so this would basically turn into a memory leak.

Since you're using Entity Framework, the best answer is probably to use ESQL, http://innocraft.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!919A8CAC315ADF82!239.entry.  This is always worked with in text format and Entity Framework will parse it out for you and run the query at runtime.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you could give your users a copy of LinqPad (which is free), and they can create their own queries, and also see the SQL text equivalent?

LinqPad can be found [here](http://www.linqpad.net)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider Dynamic LINQ.  It's still bundled with VS2010 (somwehere in the Samples folder) although it's not very well documented.  There's a brief intro here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx